# Getting the Value of the Discriminator Column

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a JPA Entity which uses a discriminator column. But I need to get access to the value of the discriminator as one of the fields of the entity.  How do I that.  If I create a method that matches the discriminator column I get the following error at deploy time:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.PortEntity column: type (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

The entity definition:

```
@Entity(name="Port")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",
         discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,
         length=10)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="port")
@Table(name="vPorts")
@XmlRootElement(name="port")
public class PortEntity {

     ...

     @Column(name="type", length=20, insert=false, update="false")
     @XmlAttribute(name="type")
     public String getType() { ... }

     public void setType(String newType) {... }

     ...

     @Entity(name="SeaPort")
     @DiscriminatorValue(value="seaport")
     @XmlRootElement(name="seaport")
     public static class Sea
     extends PortEntity { ... }



     @Entity(name="AirPort")
     @DiscriminatorValue(value="seaport")
     @XmlRootElement(name="seaport")
     public static class Air
     extends PortEntity { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want access value of `@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=10)` you may just add method like:

```
@Transient
public String getDecriminatorValue() {
    return limitString(this.getClass().getName(), 10);
}
```

if you want access it in JQPL queries you need use `TYPE` operator:
`SELECT pe FROM PortEntity as pe WHERE TYPE(pe) = SomePortEntity`

Answer (score 23):

```
@Transient
public String getDecriminatorValue() {
    return this.getClass().getAnnotation(DiscriminatorValue.class).value();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.  That project is long since past, but the knowledge is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is not good in terms of performance... If you are using JPA, let's retrieve with native queries.

```
  @Query(value = "select type from Port p where p.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<String> findIssueTypeById(@Param("id") Long id);
```